# jquery ajax unable to create php session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have an `index.html` page, where clicking a link slides down a login form.
The click event of the login button does an Ajax to a PHP scrip, where on success, the user will be redirected to another page (`test.php`).

Issue is: I don't get any errors.
The browser creates a PHPSESSID and page doesn't get redirected.
Directly browsing `test.php` results $_SESSION variable undefined error.

Code below:

PHP login script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "abcd";
$password = "12345";
$dbname = "abcdmaster";

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->msg = ''; 
$obj->err = ''; 
$obj->uname = ''; 

// Create Database connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
  die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);        
} elseif(isset($_POST['userid']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
  session_start(); 
  $username = $_POST['userid'];
  $password = $_POST['passwd'];     

  $sql = "select * FROM `adminuser` WHERE username=$username";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if($result->num_rows == 1) { 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)==0) {
      $obj->msg = "yes";
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
      $obj->uname = $_SESSION['username']; 
    } // end strcmp         
  } else {
    $obj->msg = "no";
    //$obj->err = "Invalid Login Credentials"; 
  }
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($obj);   
  return false;             
} // end isset  
?>
```

jQuery:

```
/* click event for login button */
$('.loginrow').on('click', 'input[value="Login"]', function() {
  var creds = {} 
  creds.userid = $('#userid').val(); 
  creds.passwd = $('#password').val(); 
  console.log(creds); 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/server/adminlogin.php',
    data: creds, 
    type: 'POST',   
    dataType: 'json',                   
  }).done(function(data) {
    if(data == 'yes') {
      console.log("login ok"); 
      window.location.href = './server/test.php'; 
      } else {
      console.log("login unsuccessful");
      }
  });       
  return false; 
});
```

test.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <?php
  // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
  echo "Logged on user is " . $_SESSION["username"] . ".<br>";

  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `session_start();` in adminlogin.php...

Comment: You have to add session_start to your first page

Comment: Jeez...your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this, additionally, you are storing passwords in plaintext, which you also need to fix.

Comment: @Enstage, this is not production code, it's only to demonstrate a one-off prototype. That will run locally on an XAMPP for 1 or 2 presentations lasting 2 hours each.

Comment: @Louys session_start(); is already included in adminlogin.php (view below isset() elseif clause). I've moved it to the very top just under <?php to no avail, issue persists

Comment: Okay... I didn't see it the first time. But now, what I see is in `elseif(isset($_POST['userid']) and isset($_POST['password']))` ==> `and` **should be** `&&` !!!

Comment: thanks for the reply Louys, sadly no change after changing     and to     &&

Answer (score 0):

1. Please look at your ajax `done`:

   ```
    .done(function(data) {
      if(data == 'yes') { 
        console.log("login ok"); 
        window.location.href = './server/test.php'; 
      } else {
        console.log("login unsuccessful");
      }
    });
   ```

`data` is JSON object here, so `(data == 'yes')` is always false.

You should check `(data.msg === 'yes')`.

2. Use `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},` in ajax settings to keep session cookie:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost/server/adminlogin.php',
     data: creds, 
     type: 'POST',   
     dataType: 'json', 
     xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
     ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Found a typo in `adminlogin.php` code, the line

```
elseif(isset($_POST['userid']) and isset($_POST['password']))
```

should be

```
elseif(isset($_POST['userid']) and isset($_POST['passwd']))
```

as jQuery Ajax is creating the object like:

```
var creds = {} 
  creds.userid = $('#userid').val(); 
  creds.passwd = $('#password').val();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone's help esp Kosh and Louys as what suggested by you contributed to resolving the issue too.